# How to refresh/repaint/redraw graphic in Swing for game purposes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics2d

I'm making Snake game in Java with Swing. I made game loop with `Timer`. Now I can't make my game board repaints after every move made by snake.

This is the code that is executed with timer:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(!isWon()) {
        inputDirection = inputManager.getCapturedDirection();
        try {
            snake.move(inputDirection);
        } catch (LosingMove losingMove) {
            gameLoop.stop();
            showGameOverDialog();
        }
    } else {
        gameLoop.stop();
        showWinDialog();
    }
    board.repaint();
}
```

So I tell my board object which is `Board` class extending `JPanel` to redraw the board after each move. It's `paintComponent()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int row = 0; row < size.height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size.width; col++) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fill(fields[row][col].getGraphicRepresentation());
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.draw(fields[row][col].getGraphicRepresentation());
            if (fields[row][col].getContent() instanceof Snake.SnakeNode) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g2d.fill(fields[row][col].getContent().getGraphicRepresentation());
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.draw(fields[row][col].getContent().getGraphicRepresentation());
            } else if (fields[row][col].getContent() instanceof Apple) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2d.fill(fields[row][col].getContent().getGraphicRepresentation());
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.draw(fields[row][col].getContent().getGraphicRepresentation());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`graphicRepresentation` is simply a `Shape` object.

In debugger this code is executed but It doesn't affect the window with my game board. The game is running in the background and snake is changing It's location on game board array in the memory but It isn't repainting properly. All that shows up are empty field, one snake field with incorrect place on the board (coordinates in memory are correct), and one apple field also in wrong place but with correct values in memory.

[image: screen]

How to do It the right way?

Comment: any time that you `@Override` the `paintComponent()` method, you need to call `super.paintComponent()` passing the `Graphics` object.  I don't if this will fix your problem because I don't know the coordinate values you are using.  What is the array Type of `fields
`

Comment: It didn't remove the issue but thanks for reminding it for me.

fields is of type `Field` which contains information about coordinates of the element (`Point`), it's content (apple, snake, null) and `graphicRepresentation` as `Rectangle2D`.

Comment: Do you have a game loop?  something like: `while(running)`?  if so, somewhere in that loop you should be calling `repaint()` on the `JPanel` you are painting to.  That way it repaints each frame

Comment: `repaint()` is called every second (it's delay time for timer) in `actionPerformed()`

Comment: call invalidate() just before repaint(). It might help.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't :(

Comment: It sounds to me like this might be a problem with your get graphic representation code.  have you tried just feeding dummy values in like say 6,8 to see if it would draw the proper element where expected?

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow Snake game maker, I understand some of the potential bugs involved, but there's no way

> one apple field also in wrong place but with correct values in memory.

can occur if you have set the correct co-ordinates to it.

You should try checking the instances of `Apple` and `SnakeNode` in the `fields` array again.